# yfinance refusing to work when import as yf

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I'm trying to get started with yfinance for python, however, I can't seem to get a simple command to work for it.

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

print(msft.info)

hist = msft.history(period="5d")
```

When i try to run this it give me a whole bunch of errors I don't understand. The following errors below is only about one fifth of the actual errors, and I'm sure mods wouldn't be happy if I pasted it all in, I'm sure you get the point.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1101, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 898, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 217, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 736, in _build_doc
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 717, in _build_doc
    with urlopen(self.io) as f:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 137, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

Comment: _unable to get local issuer certificate_ Sounds like certificates aren't installed correctly on your local machine.

Comment: It looks like an SSL error, so please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064876/certificate-verification-failure-for-youtube-dl) because it's the same cause of the Youtube error. `pip3 install --upgrade certifi`